# Windows 10, I always have to put computer to sleep twice

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

I'm currently running windows 10 on my computer, and when I put my computer to sleep, as soon as the LED lights on the computer turns off, the computer turns back on and shows me the lock screen where I then have to put it to sleep again and this time it works. This always happens and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. If I have missed any required information, feel free to tell me in the comments and I will update my question.

Comment: It is possible that the computer resumes because of received network packages. After computer wakes up unintended log in and execute `powercfg /lastwake` to see what caused the wake up.

Comment: @Robert It seems like Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller is causing the problem. I turned off its ability to wake the device, now when running powercfg /lastwake when it wakes up by itself, it returns `Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 0`

Comment: Most likely the Ethernet adapter triggers wake up because of incoming network packages on TCP connections still active when you out your system into standby mode.